# MainWindow closes after initialization

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qapplication

I wanted to start a new project using PyQt5 and QtDesigner. To start, I just copied the code I had from previous projects in PyQt4 and tweaked it to the changes in PyQt5. So, the code to start the `Main Window` and a `Timer` which updates the application looks like this:

```python
# ====Python=============================================================
#                               SticksNStones
# =======================================================================
import ...    

FPS = 45
dt = 1000.0 / FPS

class SNSMainWindow(WindowBaseClass, Ui_Window):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        WindowBaseClass.__init__(self, parent)
        Ui_Window.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.paused = False
        self.timer = None

        self.init()

    def init(self):    
        # Setup Display
        self.display.setup()

        # Setup timer
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_loop)

        self.timer.start(self.dt)

    def update_loop(self):
        if not self.paused:
            self.display.update(dt)
        else:
            pass


# ==================================
#           Start Application
# ==================================
_dialog = None


def start_sns():
    global _dialog

    # Start App and frame
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    _dialog = SNSMainWindow()
    _dialog.show()

    # Exit if window is closed
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_sns()
```

But as soon as I start the application, it closes after initialization. Debugging showed that the timer is active, but the `update_loop` is never called.

The PyQt4 Code from which I copied works just fine and I just can't get my head around why this does not work, since all examples I found online have the same code.

The question being: Why does the application close itself upon start?

### Update

The problem is not the timer, but the usage of a custom .ui. If I run the code with

```
class SNSMainWindow(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None): 
        QtWidgets.QFrame.__init__(self, parent) 
        ...
```

a window opens and it stays open until I close it. But a barebone

```
ui_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/ui/sns_main.ui"
Ui_Window, WindowBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(ui_path)

class SNSMainWindow(WindowBaseClass, Ui_Window):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        WindowBaseClass.__init__(self, parent)
        Ui_Window.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

# ==================================    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start App and frame
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    _dialog = SNSMainWindow()
    _dialog.show()

    # Exit if window is closed
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

just disappears within milliseconds after showing. Then again, using the custom widget in PyQt4 stays open, too. I added the `uic.load` part, which operates just fine. Am I missing something when converting to PyQt5?

### Solution

I found the solution of the problem in my custom display class. In case of a `paintEvent`, the display would try to get a (yet) undefined property. But instead of raising an exception that the property was not defined, the window just closed.

Defining the property while initializing the widget solved the problem.
This just keeps me wondering, why no exceptions are raised in this case, since the widget clearly tries to call some undefined properties. A simple

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xxx'
```

would have been enough.

Comment: guess it should be `app.exec_()`

Comment: Typo in the question. This does not change how the program behaves.

Comment: @Domino. What is the value of `self.dt`? Also: what is `self.display`, and what does its `setup()` method do? (PS: the reason why the code in your update does nothing is because a timer requires a running event-loop).

Comment: Your timer example does not work, as it needs `QApplication` to be running. So sandwich it between `app = QApplication( sys.argv )` and `app.exec_()`, you'll see that your timer will be very happy.

Comment: Another translation error. The timer does not seem to be the problem though. I expect the window to stay open even if no timer is set up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to change some lines, first try to change `app` definition to

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Then remove `Ui_Window` init and set it to `self.ui = Ui_Window()`

```
class SNSMainWindow(WindowBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        WindowBaseClass.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Window()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.paused = False
        self.timer = None

        self.init()
```

Comment: `QApplication` is found in the `QtWidgets` module since PyQt5. Since I created the UI via QtDesigner, your proposition will not work, as Ui_Window is importet via `uic`. To put it short, your recomendation does not work since `Ui_Window` is already an instance.

Comment: @Domino, First off, even if you import your `Ui_Window` using uic, it will **not** be an instance. Secondly, you cannot use an instance of an object while subclassing, thus, take it from @user3544092, and change your code to he suggested. If you have great doubts as to how uic works, please refer to qt examples like [this](https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/tree/master/examples/widgets/stylesheet), where they have shown the right way to use ui and uic

Comment: Ok, faux-pas on my side. The suggestions do work, I had to adjust access my custom frame. Still, the changes don't affect the behaviour of my code.